# Restricting types in a generic class

Tags: java, generics

This is my first time working with generics, so I'm a little unfamiliar with the terminology. Anyway, supposing I'm creating my own implementation of AbstractList:

`class MyList<T> extends AbstractList<T>`

And I've got the following three classes that I cannot change:

```
 class TestNumber
 class One extends TestNumber
 class Two extends TestNumber
 class Three extends TestNumber
 // etc...
```

Is it possible to change the type parameter for `MyList` to allow only types `One` and `Two`, but not other classes that inherit from `TestNumber`?

Comment: Create a dummy interface, have only One and Two implement it, and use it as generic type. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: @PM77-1 what if i wasn't allowed to change those classes? i forgot to mention this crucial bit earlier, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict `T` to being one of `One` or `Two`. However you can do something very similar.

Make a class `NumberType` with exactly two instances, like this:

```
public final class NumberType<T extends TestNumber> {

    public static final NumberType<One> ONE = new NumberType<One>();

    public static final NumberType<Two> TWO = new NumberType<Two>();

    private NumberType() {}
}
```

Then make your class `MyList` look like this:

```
public class MyList<T extends TestNumber> extends AbstractList<T> {

    public static <T extends TestNumber> MyList<T> newInstance(NumberType<T> type) {
        return new MyList<T>();
    }

    private MyList() {}

    // Class body omitted
}
```

Because the constructor of `MyList` is private, the only way to instantiate a new `MyList` is to use the static `newInstance()` method. The code to instantiate a `MyList` looks like this:

```
List<One> list1 = MyList.newInstance(NumberType.ONE);

List<Two> list2 = MyList.newInstance(NumberType.TWO);
```

It is not possible to instantiate a `MyList<Three>`.